# Unable to write from pubsub to BigQuery in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am sending the JSON data to the pub-sub topic. Below is the code snippet. My intention is to parse the data from pub-sub and do minor transformations and send it to BigQuery.

**publishEvents.py**

```
import json
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from concurrent import futures
from typing import Callable

project='nectar-259905'
topic='incomingData'
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path( project, topic)
publish_futures = []

def get_callback(
    publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future, data: str
) -> Callable[[pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future], None]:
    def callback(publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future) -> None:
        try:
            # Wait 60 seconds for the publish call to succeed.
            print(publish_future.result(timeout=60))
        except futures.TimeoutError:
            print(f"Publishing {data} timed out.")

    return callback

for line in open('/home/test/Resources/Input/Input_Data.json', 'r'):
    traffic=json.loads(line)
    data=str(traffic)
    #publisher.publish(topic_path, str.encode(str(key),"utf-8"))
    publish_future=publisher.publish(topic_path,data.encode("utf-8"))
    publish_future.add_done_callback(get_callback(publish_future, data))
    publish_futures.append(publish_future)
futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

print(f"Published messages with error handler to {topic_path}.")
```

**Input_Data.json**

```
{
    "user_id": "102105290400257936",
    "event_ts": "2021-05-29 00:03:12.262 UTC",
    "event_id": "Change_User_Name",
    "country": "US",
    "game": "gru",
    "user_group": "[1, 529701]",
    "user_condition": "[1]",
    "device_type": "tablet",
    "device_model": "iPhone13,2",
    "user_name": "Gin47709426",
    "fb_connect": false,
    "event_payload": "{\"trigger\":\"install\"}",
    "is_active_event": true
}
```

**readFromPubSub.py**

```
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import window
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions

from datetime import datetime
import json

def parse_json_message(message):
    """Parse the input json message and add 'score' & 'processing_time' keys."""
    row = json.loads(message)
    return {
'user_id':row['user_id'],
'event_ts':row['event_ts'],
'create_ts':row['create_ts'],
'event_id':row['event_id'],
'ifa':row['ifa'],
'ifv':row['ifv'],
'country':row['country'],
'chip_balance':row['chip_balance'],
'game':row['game'],
'user_group':row['user_group'],
'user_condition':row['user_condition'],
'device_type':row['device_type'],
'device_model':row['device_model'],
'user_name':row['user_name'],
'fb_connect':row['fb_connect'],
'is_active_event':row['is_active_event'],
'event_payload':row['event_payload']
    }


def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--subscription',
        dest='subscription',
        default='projects/nectar-259905/subscriptions/bq_subscribe',
        help='Input Pub/Sub subscription')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--table_spec ',
        dest='table_spec',
        default='nectar-259905:JSONData.bq_table',
        help='Destination BigQuery table.')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    options = PipelineOptions()
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True



    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        table_schema = {
            'fields': [

  {
    "name": "user_id",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "event_ts",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "create_ts",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "event_id",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "ifa",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "ifv",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "country",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "chip_balance",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "game",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "user_group",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "user_condition",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "device_type",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "device_model",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "user_name",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "fb_connect",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "BOOLEAN"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "is_active_event",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "BOOLEAN"

    
  },
  {
    "name": "event_payload",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"

    
  }
            ]
        }

        (p
            | 'Read from pubsub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.subscription)
            | 'Parse JSON messages' >> beam.Map(parse_json_message)
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                        known_args.table_spec,
                        schema=table_schema,
                        #method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS,
                        #triggering_frequency=1,
                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED))

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

When I execute the code `readFromPubSub.py` it gets stuck at
[image]

The insert to BQ doesn't happen. Any pointers if I am doing something wrong in schema or while parsing the message from function`parse_json_message`?

Answer (score 1):

You question shows an error on this line :

```py
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
```

It's better to not set this options in the pipeline code.

You can set it directly as a [pipeline option](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/) in the command line that launches the `Dataflow` job :

```bash
python -m folder.your_main \
    --project=my-project\
    --streaming \
```

This option isn't mandatory and no need to set it, your read an unbounded source and `Dataflow` will deduct that is a streaming job.